# Is there a way to compare the date I chose from calendar to displayed date?

Tags: selenium

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"]').click()
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.visibility_of_element_located((
    By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.react-datepicker__day--today'))).text)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.react-datepicker__day--today').click()
```

this is part of my code, I am using it to select a date from calendar, the chosen date is "Today" this date is dynamic. Need to compare that the today date is actual todays.
Is there a way to do the comparison?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Save web elements text as string, then convert it to date object, and compare to real  date.
For example: https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-date-in-python